# Laravel_php terminate the request by sending a response at any given condition

Tags: php, laravel

I built a login backend where I want to check some conditions before allowing the login.
I could check all conditions in one shoot but I need to send a different response for every failed attempt.

In the `index` method below all check methods are called, the specific thing I need is that if any condition is true then the request should terminate and the response should be sent back without calling other methods after it.
Currently the `return` at every method seems not respected.

```
public function index(LoginRequest $request){
    $user = User::select('leave','role','id','isActive')->find(request('username'));
    $this->checkRole($user);
    $this->checkAnnualLeave($user);
    $this->checkAccountDisabled($user);
}

public function checkRole($user){
    $Condition1=true;

    if($Condition1){
       return response()->json(['message'=>'user is anauthorized !']);
    }
}

public function checkAnnualLeave($user){
    $Condition2=true;

    if($Condition2){
        return response()->json(['message'=>'user is in Annual leave']);
    }
}

public function checkAccountDisabled($user){
    $ConditioN3=true;

    if($ConditioN3){ 
       return response()->json(['message'=>'user account is disabled']); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is better to use middleware for this purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can abort within every conditional returning the wanted error code and message.

```
public function index(LoginRequest $request){
    $user = User::select('leave','role','id','isActive')->find(request('username'));
    $this->checkRole($user);
    $this->checkAnnualLeave($user);
    $this->checkAccountDisabled($user);
}

public function checkRole($user){
    $Condition1=true;

    if($Condition1){
        abort(403, 'user is anauthorized !');
    }
}

public function checkAnnualLeave($user){
    $Condition2=true;

    if($Condition2){
        abort(404, 'user is in Annual leave');
    }
}

public function checkAccountDisabled($user){
    $ConditioN3=true;

    if($ConditioN3){ 
        abort(401, 'user account is disabled');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

However, I think using 'Laravel Middleware' can simplify your code, but even in your current code you can use `die()` in each of your functions after return to stop the script from running. Like bellow:

```
if($Condition1){
   return response()->json(['message'=>'user is anauthorized !']);
   die();
}
```

Another option is that check all conditions in one function. For instance, consider the following code:

```
public function index(LoginRequest $request){
    $user = User::select('leave','role','id','isActive')->find(request('username'));
    $this->checkUser($user);
}


public function checkUser($user) {
    Switch ($user) {
        case condition1:
            return response()->json(['message'=>'user is anauthorized !']);
            break;
        case condition2:
            return response()->json(['message'=>'user is in Annual leave']);
            break;
        case condition3:
            return response()->json(['message'=>'user account is disabled']); 
            break;
        default:
    }
}
```

Or you can use 'if statement' instead of 'switch statement'

Comment: The first code snippet will not work. You are calling `die()` __after__ the `return` statement, so anything after that will never be reached.